# How to create sub folder in file cabinet using suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Want to create Subfolder(Folder inside folder) in file cabinet using Suitescript 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use record module:

```
var folder = record.create({ type: record.Type.FOLDER});
folder.setValue({ fieldId: 'name',
                  value: 'Create from SuiteScript' });
folder.setValue({ fieldId: 'parent',
                  value: '' }); 
var folderId = folder.save();
```

Comment: Hi vVinceth, thanks for the reply.  I have parent folder and want to create folder in that folder.

Comment: My code is :    var objRecord = record.create({
            type: record.Type.FOLDER,
           parent: 2453,
            isDynamic: true
        });

Comment: i updated the script, have a look